Should I use WorkManager, JobScheduler, or a Service with HeadlessJsTaskService in a React Native app?
I'm currently working on a React Native app and dealing with background tasks on Android. I need to run a task to clear the cache, when app is in the backhround. The task executes some JavaScript logic via HeadlessJsTaskService with a timeout of 4 hours. I'm looking for the best way to ensure this task runs reliably in the background, especially on modern Android versions (Android 8.0+).
What I've Tried:

Service + HeadlessJsTaskService:
I initially used a background Service to start the HeadlessJsTaskService, but this led to issues when the app was killed by android system due to low memory leading to a crash with exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tried to start task headlessClearCache while in foreground, but this is not allowed.

JobScheduler:
I considered JobScheduler since it's designed for background work, but I'm having an exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent, app is in background.
Bit this is exactly what I need, it's the complete opposite of the first solution. So I'm bit confused.

WorkManager:
I've seen recommendations to use WorkManager for background tasks, However, I'm unsure if WorkManager is the right fit for triggering a HeadlessJsTaskService.


Advice from a Google SME:
A Google SME on Android background work recommended continuing to use HeadlessJsTaskService for React Native apps. They suggested considering WorkManager or a Foreground Service for tasks that run in the background and warned that HeadlessJsTaskService alone may not work reliably on newer Android versions without custom Android code.
Here's the relevant Android documentation they referred me to.
https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks
And the link to comment https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36816#issuecomment-2214528619
My Question:
Given my use case (a React Native app needing to clear cache every 4 hours), what would you recommend:
WorkManager + HeadlessJsTaskService?
JobScheduler + HeadlessJsTaskService?
Service + HeadlessJsTaskService?
Or any other approach?
I need a solution that works reliably in the background and follows Android's best practices for background execution.
Would appreciate any insights or experiences you’ve had with similar tasks!
Thanks in advance!

A Service won't work, because they can't be reliably run in the background-  they will be killed eventually.  JobScheduler could work with native code, but can't launch a background service.  WorkManager-  maybe?  WorkManager automatically runs a foreground service for you, it may be able to launch a background service.  But really, React native is a poor solution to this, and I'd look at doing whatever is needed natively instead.

When you suggest not doing this in React Native, do you mean I should implement the entire background task in native Android code (Java/Kotlin)? If so, which native approach would you recommend for periodically clearing the cache when the app is not running — JobScheduler, WorkManager, or Foreground Service? Also, how can I integrate this native solution with my React Native codebase to trigger or communicate results back effectively?"

Yes, doing the entire background job in Kotlin or Java would be easier that trying to get it to work in RN.  I'd suggest WorkManager, as this is the type of work that doesn't need a strict schedule, but can be done when the phone has free time.  Interacting with RN for results is going to be... difficult.  One of the reasons I generally wouldn't choose to do anything in RN for a complex app. Part of that depends on what communication you need back-  can it just be data written that you check next time the app runs, or do you need RN code called now?  The second is much harder.
